# How launch a python script with roslaunch

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to launch a script called mtnode.py from a package called xsens_drive. When I use rosrun it works perfectly, however i have difficulty to launch it with roslaunch. This is the syntax that I use:

```
  <node pkg="xsens_drive" name="mtnode.py" type="mtnode.py" output="screen">
        <param name="frame_id" value="base_link" />
  </node>
```

and this is the warning and error form the roslaunch:

```
WARNING: WARN: illegal <node> name 'mtnode.py'.
http://ros.org/wiki/Names
This will likely cause problems with other ROS tools.
Node xml is <node name="mtnode.py" output="screen" pkg="xsens_drive" type="mtnode.py">
        <param name="frame_id" value="base_link"/>
  </node>
```

and the error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [xsens_drive/mtnode.py]: xsens_drive
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/sherpa/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

I tried different combination of name and type without .py with no luck,
I am using ros indigo

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229841/how-launch-a-python-script-with-roslaunch/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <node pkg="xsens_drive" name="mtnode.py" type="mtnode.py" output="screen">
> ```

I think the package is actually called [xsens_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/xsens_driver), so the following should work:

```
<node pkg="xsens_driver" name="mtnode" type="mtnode.py" output="screen"> 
  ..
</node>
```

The `type` for a Python script is always just the script itself. The name can be anything, but must follow the [ROS naming conventions](http://ros.org/wiki/Names).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2016-04-07**:
Thanks, yep that was a stupid mistake of mine...

**Comment by [Haresh Karnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33873/haresh-karnan/) on 2018-02-26**:
This was useful, Thankyou !

**Comment by [meterix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35819/meterix/) on 2018-06-11**:
I did the same mistake, thank you!

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2018-06-29**:
In my case (Kinetic), the node name was not sufficient, I had to specify `nodename.py`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Additionally, make sure that the python script is executable (has execute bit set to 1), i.e. can be run with `./my_script.py`

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make the python script executable
chmod +x python_script_name.py

So give pkg= "name of package where script lies"
name ="name of python script without extension"
type="name of python scrupt with extension"

Example :

```
<node pkg="v1robot_description" name="fake_encoder_count" type="fake_encoder_count.py" output="screen"/>
```

Name of python script in my case: fake_encoder_count.py
Name of my ROS package : v1robot_description

---

Originally posted by [Sanjuna Mariam Mathews](https://answers.ros.org/users/52804/sanjuna-mariam-mathews/) with karma: 51 on 2020-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As, @rufus mentioned above make sure the file is executable.
You can to do that with below command:
`$ chmod +x python_script.py`

---

Originally posted by [Yash Sahu](https://answers.ros.org/users/77136/yash-sahu/) with karma: 71 on 2021-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1